# How to know chrome extension is in development or production environment?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

You often face situations where you have to set different variables for development and production environments. For example, if your extension has to access external API, you want to disable this when you are running your development version. So far, I've checked the `chrome.runtime.id` to see if it matches the published one's id.

Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at [management.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-get), it will return information about the installed extension/app, and you can distinguish the environment by checking the `installType` of the returned info.

> ExtensionInstallType
>
> How the extension was installed. One of
>
> - admin: The extension was installed because of an administrative policy,
> - development: The extension was loaded unpacked in developer mode,
> - normal: The extension was installed normally via a .crx file,
> - sideload: The extension was installed by other software on the machine,
> - other: The extension was installed by other means.

Comment: Even better may be to use [management.getSelf](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getSelf) which "can be used without requesting the 'management' permission in the manifest"

Comment: when installType == admin it means it was the user who installed it on production?